# Redirect loop in apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I am trying the following redirect rule, but it ends in redirect loop. Is there any way to avoid it?

There are multiple domains and based on the file accesses respective file should be served from `sitemap` directory.

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap.(.+?).0.xml.gz\/?$ /sitemap/sitemap.$1.0.xml.gz [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to escape the `.`

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.(.+?)\.0\.xml\.gz/?$ /sitemap/sitemap.$1.0.xml.gz [R=301,L]
```